# Cómo cambiar de directorio en la terminal con python?

Tags: python, unix

Quiero cambiar de directorio con python en mi terminal, para cuando se termine de ejecutar el programa, termine en el directorio que yo elegí. Intenté usar:

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import call

os.chdir("ruta")
call("ls")
```

Sí cambia la ruta, sin embargo, cuando el programa termina de ejecutarse, regresa a la ruta original donde fue ejecutado.

Cómo hago que cuando termine la ejecución, el programa continúe en la ruta que elegí? Qué comando uso?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que eso sea posible. El intérprete es lanzado por el shell del sistema y no creo que puedas modificar el entorno una vez iniciado. O al menos es lo que creo. En todo caso, podrías usar un encadenamiento al ejecutar tu aplicación o script de python. Algo como `python script.py && cd otro_directorio`. Pero nunca lo he probado. Saludos

Comment: Porque te interesa en donde termina un programa si al terminar ya ha concluido su función? Otra cosa que puedes hacer es añadir el programa a las variables de ambiente del sistema de modo que haces `cd directorio && variable-que-ejecuta-programa` y luego al cerrarse el programa deberias seguir en el directorio inicial.

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que ocurre dentro de un script en python se ejecuta en su propia instancia de shell. Cuando sales, devuelve el control al shell que lo invocó.

Lo que sí se puede hacer es que el script en python te abra una shell en la carpeta que quieras.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import os

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('carpeta', help='carpeta donde navegar: ./cd.py ruta/a/carpeta')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    os.chdir(args.carpeta)
    os.system('bash')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

con eso (pensando que lo hiciste ejecutable)

```
usuario@host:/tmp$ ./cd.py /var/lib
usuario@host:/var/lib$
```

pero esa shell no es la misma desde donde empezaste, y si sales de esta shell hija, vuelves al inicio:

```
usuario@host:/var/lib$ exit
usuario@host:/tmp$
```